Why the xelatex-biber-xelatex-xelatex compile failed?
I compile the following .tex file get compile error. Why?
I compiled it using recipes xelatex-biber-xelatex-xelatex,then get the error message. Is the xampl.bib didn't fit the case?

Here below is the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{zhlipsum}
\usepackage[style=gb7714-2015]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xampl.bib}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Here is a cite\cite{article-full}.

\zhlipsum[8]

这是另一处中文引用\cite{misc-full}.

\lipsum[3]

\printbibliography
\end{document}

To be more detailed, if I manually use the command line by:
xelatex biblatex_mwe
biber biblatex_mwe
xelatex biblatex_mwe
xelatex bilatex_mwe

The Log message is as follow:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./biblatex_mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexhook.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexpatch.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctexopts.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/engine/ctex-engine-xetex.def
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhnumber/zhnumber.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhnumber/zhnumber-utf8.cfg))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/scheme/ctex-scheme-chinese.def
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctex-name-utf8.cfg))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctex-c5size.clo)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-fontset-windows.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctex.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhlipsum/zhlipsum.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhlipsum/zhlipsum-utf8.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-gb7714-2015/gb7714-2015.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric-comp.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-gb7714-2015/gb7714-2015.cbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty))
No file biblatex_mwe.aux.
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
No file biblatex_mwe.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'article-full' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'misc-full' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.

[1]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 18.

[2] (./biblatex_mwe.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                biblatex_mwe
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )
Output written on biblatex_mwe.pdf (2 pages).
Transcript written on biblatex_mwe.log.

INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'biblatex_mwe.blg'
INFO - Reading 'biblatex_mwe.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'xampl.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'd:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/base/xampl.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'none/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'none' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'biblatex_mwe.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to biblatex_mwe.bbl
WARN - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\Explorer\AppData\Local\Temp\biber_tmp_H2eS\bcacf93a0eaac1ec403e8333b676661e_77736.utf8, line 34, warning: 125 characters of junk seen at toplevel
INFO - WARNINGS: 1

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./biblatex_mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexhook.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexpatch.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctexopts.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/engine/ctex-engine-xetex.def
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhnumber/zhnumber.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhnumber/zhnumber-utf8.cfg))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/scheme/ctex-scheme-chinese.def
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctex-name-utf8.cfg))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctex-c5size.clo)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-fontset-windows.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctex.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhlipsum/zhlipsum.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhlipsum/zhlipsum-utf8.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-gb7714-2015/gb7714-2015.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric-comp.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-gb7714-2015/gb7714-2015.cbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty))
(./biblatex_mwe.aux)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./biblatex_mwe.bbl) [1]
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.19 \end
         {document}
?
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\mbox  #1->\leavevmode \hbox {#1}

l.19 \end
         {document}
?

Overfull \hbox (4.7395pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--19
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/10.53937 MISSILANY J B. Handing out random pamphlets in airports[
Z]. Handed
[2] (./biblatex_mwe.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please rerun LaTeX.

 )
Output written on biblatex_mwe.pdf (2 pages).
Transcript written on biblatex_mwe.log.

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./biblatex_mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexhook.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexpatch.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctexopts.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/engine/ctex-engine-xetex.def
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhnumber/zhnumber.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhnumber/zhnumber-utf8.cfg))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/scheme/ctex-scheme-chinese.def
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctex-name-utf8.cfg))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctex-c5size.clo)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-fontset-windows.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/config/ctex.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhlipsum/zhlipsum.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zhlipsum/zhlipsum-utf8.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-unicode.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-gb7714-2015/gb7714-2015.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric-comp.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex)))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-gb7714-2015/gb7714-2015.cbx
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric-comp.cbx))
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty))
(./biblatex_mwe.aux)
(d:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
(./biblatex_mwe.bbl) [1]
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }
l.19 \end
         {document}
?
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\mbox  #1->\leavevmode \hbox {#1}

l.19 \end
         {document}
?

Overfull \hbox (4.7395pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--19
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/10.53937 MISSILANY J B. Handing out random pamphlets in airports[
Z]. Handed
[2] (./biblatex_mwe.aux) )
Output written on biblatex_mwe.pdf (2 pages).
Transcript written on biblatex_mwe.log.

It actually perform the right pdf, but there are two bugs in the second and third xelatex with ! Missing } inserted.
What's more, is that I configured my settings.json file in VScode as followed:
  "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
      "name": "xelatex",
      "command": "xelatex",
      "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "%DOCFILE%"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "biber",
      "command": "biber",
      "args": [
        "%DOCFILE%"
      ]
    },
  ],
 "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
      "name": "XeLaTeX -> Biber -> XeLaTeX*2",
      "tools": [
        "xelatex",
        "biber",
        "xelatex",
        "xelatex"
      ]
    },
]

After I use the recipe XeLaTeX -> Biber -> XeLaTeX*2, I get the result of two errors. What actually confused me a lot. Thx!

With your code I get no error.

I repeat my compile again. And I found that if I conduct the compile command via command line, like   xelatex  ,  biber  , xelatex , xelatex , it actually didn't show any error, but I notice at at the log file, it indicated that:  ! Missing } inserted.

}
l.19 \end
{document}
?
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\mbox  #1->\leavevmode \hbox {#1}
l.19 \end
{document}
? But it can produce the pdf file.

While when I use the recipes provided by the LaTeXworkshop in Vscode, the result is shown as that in the question. I will add more details to the problem.

I can reproduce the error, on the xelatex run after the biber run.

I am a beginner of biblatex, as @Marijn says, the error actually happen at the last two xelatex, could someone told me the reason? Thx!

It does have something to do with xampl.bib. If I change that to biblatex-examples.bib (which is also installed by default) then there is no error.

More specifically it seems to be the article-full entry in xampl.bib, for example \cite{whole-collection} works ok (and misc-full also works). The article-full entry starts with an \mbox{} in the journal field that produces the error (when the mbox is not at the start of the field it works ok).

Thanks to yr patient and brilliant answer, I change the example .bib file and the .tex doc is compiled successfully! Then I wonder is there any differences between two .bib files? That is to say, if someone give me a .bib file, I have to try or ask him is it fit both the bibtex and biber or just one?

Most bib files are compatible with both, although biblatex files can have some fields that are unknown to bibtex. But sometimes it will be needed to change an entry a little bit to make it compatible. So my advice is to just try it out, and in the few cases where it doesn't work then either try the other system or change/simplify the entry manually.

Some more debugging information: it is specifically the gb7714-2015 style that causes the problem, without it the entry with the \mbox works fine.

I've learned a lot and I can't thank you enough for that!
